# referencing edmx in mvc project

Tags: entity-framework

I have a EF connection string in an MVC project like so:

> connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.db.csdl|res://*/Models.db.ssdl|res://*/Models.db.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SystemName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

All is well until I added a second project and referenced the MVC project that contains the edmx, but during runtime I get:

The specified metadata path is not valid. A valid path must be either an existing directory, an existing file with extension '.csdl', '.ssdl', or '.msl', or a URI that identifies an embedded resource.

I've read post after post, but I can't figure out how to correctly reference the metadata in the MVC project. Can someone point me in the correct direction? I don't want to create a connection string that is so specific it breaks during deployment and debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format for resources is:

```
Metadata=res://<assemblyFullName>/<resourceName>.
```

The lazy way is to use a wild card res://*/bah.msl.  Which would load the model/mapping files from the bin directory, calling assembly, as well as referenced assemblies.

In your case:

```
res:///Models.db.csdl|res:///Models.db.ssdl|res://*/Models.db.msl
```

Is incorrect, try:

```
res://*/Models.db.csdl|res://*/Models.db.ssdl|res://*/Models.db.msl
```

Complete string:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.db.csdl|res://*/Models.db.ssdl|res://*/Models.db.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SystemName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

---

Alternatively you could use absolute references which is faster(but I am assuming this will be much more painful for you):

```
Metadata=res://<DLL>, <Version>, neutral, <SN>/Models.db.csdl|Models.db.ssdl|Models.db.msl
```

Comment: When I try the //*/ string VS crashes. Microsoft Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close.

Comment: And you used my connectionString from above?  Please make sure you see that I replaced your `provider connection string="` with `provider connection string='`